# Halving my yeast for two batches

Tags: yeast

I am about to start a batch again, as I have now run out of beer.  I am brewing in smaller batches (8 litres).  I plan on splitting the wort and putting then into two separate fermenters.  Since a single pack of yeast is generally good for 25 litres, I want to take a single pack of dry Nottingham ale yeast and want to know if I can just split it in half and throw each into the fermenter?  The yeast is probably the most expensive ingredient for me - so it would make a difference to me.  I would still like the beer to have a ABV of around +4%.

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  You're ideally looking for a certain number of cells per milliliter per gravity of the wort.  So, using a half-packet of yeast for a half-sized batch will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I am looking forward to some home-brew very soon.  My batches are "quick" 2 week ones.